# What can be said about $a,b,c$ or $(b+c),(c+a),(a+b)$ if three real numbers $a,b,c$ are such that $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are terms of an AP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

Question: Three real numbers $a,b,c$ are such that $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are terms of an arithmetic progression. Then

(A) $a,b,c$ are terms of a geometric progression

(B) $(b+c),(c+a),(a+b)$ are terms of an arithmetic progression

(C) $(b+c),(c+a),(a+b)$ are terms of a harmonic progression

(D) none of the foregoing statements is necessarily true

I cannot figure out how to solve this question. Initially I misread the question and took $a^2,b^2,c^2$ to be in arithmetic progression but then I realized that they are terms of an arithmetic progression and not necessarily in arithmetic progression. I cannot figure how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: I suggest trying to find counterexamples

Comment: If you have found a counterexample where $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are in arithmetic progression, then you have found a counterexample where $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are terms of an arithmetic progression. So no worries there, it doesn't matter. Of course, if you aim to prove that one of these statements is true, then yes, it does matter. And it could be that there are only counterexamples where $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are non-consecutive terms. But I think you should focus on the easiest case first, see what you can find.

Comment: @Arthur, if $a=4,b=8,c=10$ then $a^2=16,b^2=64,c^2=100$ are the terms of an AP.  But neither (A) nor (B) nor (C) is satisfied in this case. Then option (D) must be correct. What do you think?

Comment: @MrAP, would you like to accept any of these answers? :-)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173813/if-b-c-c-a-a-b-are-in-h-p-then-find-the-relation-between-df/4371223#4371223 [work done in the question post]

Answer (score 1):

I think the question means that the terms are in AP. I've solved it accordingly.

$\begin{align}
2b^2&=a^2+c^2\\
b^2-a^2&=c^2-b^2\\
\frac{b-a}{b+c}&=\frac{c-b}{b+a}\\
\frac{(b+c)-(a+c)}{(b+c)(a+c)}&=\frac{(a+c)-(a+b)}{(a+b)(a+c)}&&\text{...(divide both sides by $(a+c)$)}\\
\frac{1}{a+c}-\frac{1}{b+c}&=\frac{1}{a+b}-\frac{1}{a+c}\\
\frac{2}{a+c}&=\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}
\end{align}$

Hence, $(b+c), \;(c+a), \;(a+b)$ are in HP.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that nor a) neither b) are true, it suffices to consider $a,b,c>0,\; a^2=1, b^2=5,c^2=9.$

---

The numbers $b+c, c+a, a+b$ from the above example are in harmonic progression. Let us see if it is so in general.

It suffices to prove that the harmonic mean of $b+c$ and $a+b$ equals $c+a,$ assuming that $(b+c)\neq0\neq (a+b).$

$$HM(b+c,a+b)=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+b}}$$
Therefore $$HM(b+c,a+b)=\frac{2(b+c)(a+b)}{a+2b+c}=\frac{2ab+2ac+a^2+c^2+2bc}{a+2b+c}$$

Since $a^2+c^2=2b^2,$ we have
$$HM(b+c,a+b)=\frac{(a+2b+c)(c+a)}{a+2b+c}.$$

If $(b+c)\neq0\neq (a+b),$ then the statement c) is true.

---

Without assuming $(b+c)\neq0\neq (a+b)$ or, e.g. $a,b,c>0$ (there is no constraint in the exercise!) holds d).
As a counterexample to c), consider $a=1, b=-1, c=1.$