# If $(b + c) , (c + a) , (a + b)$ are in H.P. then find the relation between $\dfrac{a}{b+c} , \dfrac{b}{c+a} , \dfrac{c}{a+b}$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> If $(b + c) , (c + a) , (a + b)$ are in H.P. then $\dfrac{a}{b+c} , \dfrac{b}{c+a} , \dfrac{c}{a+b}$ are in $(i)$ A.P. $(ii)$ G.P. $(iii)$ H.P. $(iv)$ None of These.

**What I Tried**:- I have that $(b+c),(c+a),(a+b)$ are in H.P. .

$\implies \dfrac{1}{b+c}, \dfrac{1}{c+a}, \dfrac{1}{a+b}$ are in A.P. .

$\implies \dfrac{1}{c+a} - \dfrac{1}{b+c} = \dfrac{1}{a+b} - \dfrac{1}{c+a}.$

$\implies \dfrac{(b + c) - (c + a)}{(c + a)(b+c)} = \dfrac{(c+a) - (a+b)}{(a+b)(c+a)}.$

$\implies \dfrac{(b - a)}{(b + c)} = \dfrac{(c - b)}{(b + a)}.$

$\implies (b^2 - a^2) = (c^2 - b^2).$

$\implies 2b^2 = a^2 + c^2.$

So I was able to prove that $a^2 , b^2 , c^2$ are in A.P. , but I am not sure how to show the claim in the question.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: Hint: Add $1$ to each of the terms.

Comment: Okay, also can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: Downvote's not mine, but the term "in H.P." is unclear to me. Maybe that's what caused it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As , $a^2,b^2,c^2$ & $\frac{1}{(b+c)}, \frac{1}{(c+a)}, \frac{1}{(a+b)}$ are in $AP$ then , $$\frac{2}{(c+a)}=\frac{1}{(b+c)}+\frac{1}{(a+b)}$$ $$\frac{2b}{(c+a)}=\frac{b}{(b+c)}+\frac{b}{(a+b)}$$ $$\frac{2b}{(c+a)}=\frac{ba+\color{green}{b^2+b^2}+bc}{(a+b)(b+c)}$$

Since we have $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are in $AP$ , we have : $$2b^2=a^2+c^2$$

So , finally $$\frac{2b}{(c+a)}=\frac{\color{blue}{a^2+ab}+\color{red}{c^2+cb}}{(a+b)(b+c)}$$ $$\frac{2b}{(c+a)}=\frac{\color{blue}{a(a+b)}+\color{red}{c(b+c)}}{\color{blue}{(a+b)}\color{red}{(b+c)}}$$ $$\color{green}{\frac{2b}{(c+a)}=\frac{a}{(b+c)}+\frac{c}{(a+b)}}$$

We're DONE . Hence its in $AP$ .
**Please consider UpVoting**

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

Add $1$ to each term as mentioned in the comments by @SathvikAcharya

Hint 2:

If $p,q,r$ is an arithmetic progression, $\lambda p,\lambda q,\lambda r$ is also an arithmetic progression where $\lambda$ is a real number

Answer (score 1):

Just to show another way this might be written:

Once you demonstrated that
$ \ \dfrac{1}{b+c} \ , \ \dfrac{1}{c+a} \ ,  \ \dfrac{1}{a+b} \ $ in arithmetic progression implies that

$$ \ \dfrac{1}{c+a} - \dfrac{1}{b+c} \ = \ \dfrac{1}{a+b} - \dfrac{1}{c+a} \  \implies \ \dfrac{(b - a)}{(c + a)·(b+c)} \ = \ \dfrac{(c  -  b)}{(a+b)·(c+a)} \ \ , \quad \quad \mathbf{[1]} $$
it is already becoming clear that $ \ \dfrac{a}{b+c} \ , \ \dfrac{b}{c+a} \ ,  \ \dfrac{c}{a+b} \ $ is unlikely to be a geometric series as there are   *differences* of terms in the numerators of the ratios in equation $ \ \mathbf{[1]} \ \ .  $ Similarly, the "single-number" numerators of the ratios in the sequence do not appear consistent with their *reciprocals* being in arithmetic progression.  So we will want to test whether the ratios themselves are in arithmetic progression; otherwise, we will need to choose $ \ \mathbf{(iv)} \ \ . \ \ $  (This looks to be a reasonable route of investigation, since the differences of sequence terms will produce the same products of factors in the denominators.)

$$ \dfrac{b}{c+a} \ - \ \dfrac{a}{b+c} \ \ = \ \  \dfrac{ b^2 \ + \ bc \ - \  ac \ - \ a^2}{(c + a)·(b+c)} \ \ = \ \ \dfrac{ (b - a) \ · \ [ \ (b + a) \ + c \ ] }{(c + a)·(b+c)} \ \ , $$
$$ \dfrac{c}{a+b} \ - \ \dfrac{b}{c+a} \ \ = \ \  \dfrac{ c^2 \ + \ ac \ - \  ab \ - \ b^2}{(a + b)·(c+a)} \ \ = \ \ \dfrac{ (c - b) \ · \ [ \ (c + b) \ + a \ ] }{(a + b)·(c+a)} \ \ . $$

These two ratios have the common factor $ \ a + b + c \ $ in their numerators, so by equation $ \ \mathbf{[1]} \ \ ,  $ we can establish that $ \ \dfrac{ (b - a) \ · \ ( \ a + b + c \ ) }{(c + a)·(b+c)} \ = \ \dfrac{ (c - b) \ · \ ( \ a + b + c \ ) }{(a + b)·(c+a)} \ \ . $  Hence, there is a common difference between the terms of the sequence $ \ \dfrac{a}{b+c} \ , \ \dfrac{b}{c+a} \ ,  \ \dfrac{c}{a+b} \ \ , $ making this an arithmetic progression [choice $ \ \mathbf{(i)} \ ] \  .   $